# Exporting a PNG fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, png

I'm trying to generate a png image using the below command, however, the code only generates a pdf file, what is the problem?

I used terminal and the command pdflatex  --shell-escape test.tex [image: error in terminal]

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     xlabel={$t$(ms)},
     grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     ylabel={$v(t)$},
     axis lines=left,
    scaled ticks=false,
    width=15cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    minor tick num=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
    ytick={-1,1},
    yticklabels={$-100$,$100$},
    xtick={.3333,0.8333,1.3333,1.83333,2.3333},
    xticklabels={5.5557,$13.8890$,$22.2224$,$30.5557$,$38.8891$},
     x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=0,below}                        
            ]

     \addplot[domain=0:2,samples=50,smooth,black, ultra thick] {cos(deg(2*pi*x-(2*pi/3)))};

\end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you even have imagemagick installed? That software provides the `convert` command that is being used.

Comment: I did download this folder inside my application ImageMagick-7.0.10

Comment: but can it find it via the command line? I don't use Mac so I don't know how things work regarding paths on a Mac

Comment: @daleif As noted in an answer, the ImageMagick `convert` command must not be used on Windows (for many years) because Windows has a system `convert` command. The correct ImageMagick command is `magick convert` (or `gm convert` if using GraphicsMagick. Also works on Linux. Unfortunately, many users (not on Windows) request `convert` because it does not conflict on Linux. Not sure about Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Tex Live on Windows 11.  I was finally able to produce a PNG file by executing the following TEX file from the Windows 11 command line.  If executed from the TexWorks editor it is unsuccessful (pertinent log file lines below.)

On the way to getting this to work, I had to install two additional programs: ImageMagick and GhostWriter.  Also, I have the -shell-escape option enabled in my texmf.cnf file.  Googling helped and hindered!

The ImageMagick 'convert' command has been renamed to 'magick'.  My system has a 'convert' command that wants to convert my hard drive file system!

It turned out that ImageMagick actually uses GhostWriter code, so that had to be installed.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=640x360,outext=.png,convertexe=magick}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Trying to export a PNG!
\end{document}
```

The output obtained using the command line pdflatex:

[image]

The error logged if using TexWorks:

> runsystem(magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch PNG_out.pdf -resize
> 640x360 -quality 90 PNG_out.png)...executed.
>
> Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful! (standalone)
> There might be something wrong with your (standalone)
> conversation software or the file permissions!

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question or do you want to know, why the conversion with TeXworks doesn't work? In this case this would be a new question and should be asked as question.

Comment: I do want to know why it doesn't work and added a question after realizing what I had done.  However, I think the information provided may help with this topic's original question.